# Javascript firestore:how to get results of a where query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

my query code is this

```
 var Cloud = firebase.firestore()

     var groupRef = Cloud.collection("Groups").doc('Custom').collection('Programming')
     .doc('Group2').collection('Posts')    

     var query = groupRef.where("Name", "==", "Python").get()
     alert(query)
```

it returns me `[Object Object]`

i have also tried

```
alert(query.data())
```

and

```
alert(query.val())
```

but i get it is not a function! 
***how can i get ids of docs which contain Name as Python***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this...

```
var Cloud = firebase.firestore()
 var data-id;
 var groupRef = Cloud.collection("Groups").get().then((snapshot)=>{
 snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{ data-id = doc.id })})   

 var query = groupRef.where("Name", "==", "Python").get()
 alert(query)
```

Or you can refer this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmTECF0JZyQ&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9itfjle0ji1xOZ2cjRGY_WB&index=3